# Products Collections not loading using block in cms magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product-collection, category-products, cms-block

> app\code\Namespace\Module\Block

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

    class Catproduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {    
        protected $_storeManager;    
        protected $_productCollectionFactory;
        protected $registry;    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            array $data = []
        )
        {    
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
            $this->registry = $registry;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getCurrencySymbol() {
            return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();
        }


        public function getBasetUrl() {
           return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        }

        public function getCurrentUrl() {
           return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();
        }

        public function getStore()
        {
            return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        }


        public function getCurrentCat()
        {
        return $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        }

        public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
        {
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->setPageSize(9); // fetching only 3 products
            $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $categoryId));
            return $collection;
        }

        public function getFeaturedProducts($categoryId)
        {
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->setPageSize(3); 
            $collection->setCurPage(1); 
            $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $categoryId));
            return $collection;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates

```
<style>
.category-cms,.list-page{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<?php

$store = $block->getStore();
$category = $block->getCurrentCat();
$categoryId = $category->getId();
echo "Category Id".$categoryId;
$categoryUrl = $category->getUrl();
$collection = $block->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);

$currencySymbol = $block->getCurrencySymbol();
$curUrl = $block->getCurrentUrl();
$baseUrl = $block->getBasetUrl();
if(strpos($curUrl, "?") !== false){
 $url_check = 1;
}else{
 $url_check = 0;
}

$featuredCollection = $block->getFeaturedProducts($categoryId);
?>
<div class="featured-cat">
    <h3>Featured Products</h3>
    <div class="promorow">
        <?php 
            foreach($featuredCollection as $feature){
                 $featureName = $feature->getName();                
                 $featureImage = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $feature->getImage();
                 $featureId = $feature->getId();
                 $featureUrl = $feature->getProductUrl();
                 $featurePrice = $feature->getPrice();  
                 $featurePrice = number_format((float)$featurePrice, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00

            ?>
            <section class="featured-box">
                <a href="<?php echo $featureUrl; ?>"><img class="secChangeCollectImg1 img-responsive" src="<?php echo $featureImage; ?>" alt="Featured1" /></a>
                <a href="<?php echo $featureUrl; ?>"><h5 class="secChangeCollectTxt1"><?php echo $featureName; ?></h5></a>
            </section>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="favourites-section">
    <h2>Our Favourites</h2>
    <div class="fav-inner">
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid">
         <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php 
            foreach($collection as $product){
                 $productName = $product->getName();                
                 $productImage = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
                 $productId = $product->getId();
                 $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
                 $productPrice = $product->getPrice();  
                 $productPrice = number_format((float)$productPrice, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00

            ?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info">
                    <a href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <span class="product-image-container" style="width:240px;">
                        <span class="product-image-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 125%;">
                    <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" width="240" height="300" alt=""></span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                       <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>">
                            <?php echo $productName; ?>
                        </a>
                       </strong>
                       <div class="price-box price-final_price">
                            <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
                             <span id="product-price-<?php echo $productId; ?>" class="price-wrapper ">
                             <span class="price"><?php echo $currencySymbol.$productPrice; ?></span> </span>
                            </span>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        <?php } ?>
         </ol>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
        <section class="product-category-results">
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo $categoryUrl; ?>?p=1">SHOP ALL</a>
        </section>

        <section class="email-signup email-signup--secondary">
            <h2 class="email-signup__heading heading-level-four">KEEP UP WITH THE LATEST NEWS &amp; OFFERS</h2>
            <h3 class="heading-level-five">Sign up to receive exclusive email updates and offers from SS Britain</h3>
            <button class="email-signup__button js-email-signup-modal" id="open_model">Sign up</button>
        </section>
```

> And block i am loading like this in cms block

```
{{block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Catproduct" template="Namespace_Module::prodcat.phtml"}}
```

Comment: any system.log or any other log ?

Comment: no error found there

Answer (score 0):

Actually this whole code working only.

> app\code\Namespace\Module\Block

```
<?php
    namespace Namespace\Module\Block;

    class Catproduct extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {    
        protected $_storeManager;    
        protected $_productCollectionFactory;
        protected $registry;    
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            array $data = []
        )
        {    
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
            $this->registry = $registry;
            parent::__construct($context, $data);
        }

        public function getCurrencySymbol() {
            return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();
        }


        public function getBasetUrl() {
           return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl();
        }

        public function getCurrentUrl() {
           return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl();
        }

        public function getStore()
        {
            return $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        }


        public function getCurrentCat()
        {
        return $category = $this->registry->registry('current_category');
        }

        public function getCategoryProducts($categoryId) 
        {
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->setPageSize(9); // fetching only 3 products
            $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $categoryId));
            $collection->load();
            return $collection;
        }

        public function getFeaturedProducts($categoryId)
        {
            $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
            $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
            $collection->setPageSize(3); 
            $collection->setCurPage(1); 
            $collection->addCategoriesFilter(array('in' => $categoryId));
            $collection->load();
            return $collection;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

> app/code/Namespace/Module/view/frontend/templates

```
<style>
.category-cms,.list-page{
    display:none;
}
</style>
<?php

$store = $block->getStore();
$category = $block->getCurrentCat();
$categoryId = $category->getId();
echo "Category Id".$categoryId;
$categoryUrl = $category->getUrl();
$collection = $block->getCategoryProducts($categoryId);

$currencySymbol = $block->getCurrencySymbol();
$curUrl = $block->getCurrentUrl();
$baseUrl = $block->getBasetUrl();
if(strpos($curUrl, "?") !== false){
 $url_check = 1;
}else{
 $url_check = 0;
}

$featuredCollection = $block->getFeaturedProducts($categoryId);
?>
<div class="featured-cat">
    <h3>Featured Products</h3>
    <div class="promorow">
        <?php 
            foreach($featuredCollection as $feature){
                 $featureName = $feature->getName();                
                 $featureImage = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $feature->getImage();
                 $featureId = $feature->getId();
                 $featureUrl = $feature->getProductUrl();
                 $featurePrice = $feature->getPrice();  
                 $featurePrice = number_format((float)$featurePrice, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00

            ?>
            <section class="featured-box">
                <a href="<?php echo $featureUrl; ?>"><img class="secChangeCollectImg1 img-responsive" src="<?php echo $featureImage; ?>" alt="Featured1" /></a>
                <a href="<?php echo $featureUrl; ?>"><h5 class="secChangeCollectTxt1"><?php echo $featureName; ?></h5></a>
            </section>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="favourites-section">
    <h2>Our Favourites</h2>
    <div class="fav-inner">
        <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid">
         <ol class="products list items product-items">
            <?php 
            foreach($collection as $product){
                 $productName = $product->getName();                
                 $productImage = $store->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA) . 'catalog/product' . $product->getImage();
                 $productId = $product->getId();
                 $productUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
                 $productPrice = $product->getPrice();  
                 $productPrice = number_format((float)$productPrice, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00

            ?>
            <li class="item product product-item">
                <div class="product-item-info">
                    <a href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
                        <span class="product-image-container" style="width:240px;">
                        <span class="product-image-wrapper" style="padding-bottom: 125%;">
                    <img class="product-image-photo" src="<?php echo $productImage; ?>" width="240" height="300" alt=""></span>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="product details product-item-details">
                       <strong class="product name product-item-name">
                        <a class="product-item-link" href="<?php echo $productUrl; ?>">
                            <?php echo $productName; ?>
                        </a>
                       </strong>
                       <div class="price-box price-final_price">
                            <span class="price-container price-final_price tax weee">
                             <span id="product-price-<?php echo $productId; ?>" class="price-wrapper ">
                             <span class="price"><?php echo $currencySymbol.$productPrice; ?></span> </span>
                            </span>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>

        <?php } ?>
         </ol>
        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
        <section class="product-category-results">
            <a class="button" href="<?php echo $categoryUrl; ?>?p=1">SHOP ALL</a>
        </section>

        <section class="email-signup email-signup--secondary">
            <h2 class="email-signup__heading heading-level-four">KEEP UP WITH THE LATEST NEWS &amp; OFFERS</h2>
            <h3 class="heading-level-five">Sign up to receive exclusive email updates and offers from SS Britain</h3>
            <button class="email-signup__button js-email-signup-modal" id="open_model">Sign up</button>
        </section>
```

> And block i am loading like this in cms block

```
{{block class="Namespace\Module\Block\Catproduct" template="Namespace_Module::prodcat.phtml"}}
```